# background process log shows big gaps in message timestamps

Tags: linux, bash, shell, nohup

I started a long running job under nohup in the background over a weekend. When looking at the output after it finished, I noticed that there were large gaps between the timestamps of some log messages. Some gaps were as long as 10 hrs. I had no way of finding out what was going on with my job at that time.

I ran it on a standard Red hat linux server machine at work.

Is this behavior caused by nohup command ? If not what could be possible causes ?

One such long running job was as the script below -

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo "`date`  `top -n 1 -b | grep progname`"
done
```

And here one such gap from the log -

```
Mon May 26 04:29:42 PDT 2014  27685 user    18   0 2883m 2.8g 1732 S  0.0  3.9  29:05.54 progname
Tue May 27 03:20:35 PDT 2014  27685 user    18   0 3371m 3.3g 1732 S  0.0  4.6  34:23.21 progname
```

Comment: I cannot know from what you presented - loops like that use a lot of cpu - there may be some resource controls/software at work.  E.g., cpu quota enforcement.  Show it to your sysadmin.  After she whacks you for wasting resources, maybe you will get an answer.

Comment: @jimmcnamara I agree, this will use a lot of CPU, but I expected to see the job killed, or gaps of a few minutes would makes sense, but this is very large gap. Anyway, how can I write this better ? I was trying to monitor the RAM usage for progname there.

Comment: To give you a good answer - what UNIX/Linux are you running?

Comment: @jimmcnamara its Linux 2.6.18 x86_64, Red hat 5.7 and bash shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

pid is a variable that is the pid of the process you want to monitor--
Try this for starters (Courtesy of S Chazelas):

```
export pid=$(ps -ef | grep progname | awk '{$print $2}')
while rss=$(ps -o rss= -p "${pid}") 
do
  printf '%d %s\n' "$rss"  "$(date)"
  sleep 60; 
done > t.lis
# 
echo "Done $(date)" >> t.lis
```

rss is the resident set size (memory allocated to the process) in pages.

```
getconf PAGESIZE
```

will show how many bytes are in a page of memory.

Comment: Thanks! Actually putting a sleep in the loop solved the problem.